# How to display a version of a dependency that was added by a plugin?

Tags: android, gradle

I added [error-prone](https://github.com/google/error-prone) to my Android project like this:

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath 'net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-errorprone-plugin:0.0.10'
  }
}
```

`0.0.10` is the version of the plugin, it is not the version of the library added to the project.

If I list the dependencies using

```
./gradlew androidDependencies
```

Error prone is not displayed. If I use:

```
gradle buildenvironment
```

It displays the version of the plugin, but still I can't see what is the actual library being added to the project.

So my question is how can I display the version of a dependency that was added to an Android project via a plugin?

---

How I print all configurations:

```
task printConfigurations() {
   configurations.each { println "Configuration " + it.name }
}
```

---

Gradle dependencies is the solution:

```
❯ gradle dependencies | grep prone
\--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_core:2.0.19
     +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotation:2.0.19
     +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_check_api:2.0.19
     |    +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotation:2.0.19 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.errorprone:javac:9-dev-r3297-4
     |    \--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.0.19
     +--- com.google.errorprone:javac:9-dev-r3297-4
     \--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.0.19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gradle dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-errorprone-plugin
gradle dependencies
```

Comment: `Configuration with name 'compile' not found.` When I print all the configurations, `compile` is there

Comment: Oh ok, I see it now, if I enter the subdirectory of the actual module then it finds the correct configuration, but it doesn't find the dependency `No dependencies matching given input were found in configuration ':presentation:compile'`

Comment: @GabrielOshiro I just copied the name of the dependency, maybe it has a short name like: `net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-errorprone` (without the `-plugin`)

Comment: If I cut and paste the name of other dependencies it works. I can see the dependency tree. But for this particular dependency if I paste the name of the plugin or if I paste the name of the library added by the plugin I get the message above. So I really appreciate your help but it does not solve my issue